# Upcased method is not detected

Tags: ruby, methods

The following defines a method that has an upcased name, and attempts to call it, but fails:

```
class Module
  def Foo; puts "foo" end
end

class A
  Foo
end
# => uninitialized constant A::Foo
```

I understand that existence of a constant with the same name would take precedence over method look up, but there is no such constant in this case.

If I disambiguate it as a method, then the method is detected:

```
class A
  Foo()
end
# => foo
```

When the method name is not upcased, look up does not fail.

```
class Module
  def foo; puts "foo" end
end

class A
  foo
end
# => foo
```

Why does method look up fail with ambiguous upcased methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby has a flexible syntax for message sends. In particular, you can leave off the receiver and you can leave off the argument list. If you do both, then such a receiverless argumentless message send is syntactically indistinguishable from a variable dereference.

So, we need some rules to disambiguate between receiverless argumentless message sends and variable dereferences. And those rules are simple:

- for instance variables, class variables and global variables, there is no ambiguity
- for local variables, such a construct is always interpreted as a message send, unless a local variable is in scope, then it is interpreted as a variable dereference
- for constants, it is always interpreted as a variable dereference

Since this ambiguity only arises when there is a receiverless argumentless message send, it can easily be resolved by adding either a receiver or an argument list.

Comment: What makes the case of constants different from local variables?

Comment: The distinction between message sends and variable dereferences is made statically. Figuring out which local variables are in scope can be done statically, but for constants it would be equivalent to solving the Halting Problem. Or worse: `module Foo; Bar = :baz end; if rand > 0.5 then include Foo end; Bar # is Bar in scope or not?`

Comment: I see. I feel I got it (but am still grasping it).